# How to extract text from a column using R

Tags: r, string, extract

How would I go about extracting, for each row (there are ~56,000 records in an Excel file) in a specific column, only part of a string? I need to keep all text to the left of the last '/' forward slash. The challenge is that not all cells have the same number of '/'. There is always a filename (*.wav) at the end of the last '/', but the number of characters in the filename is not always the same (sometimes 5 and sometimes 6).

Below are some examples of the strings in the cells:
cloch/51.wav
grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde/038-D.wav
grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde/039-D#.wav
AB_AeolinaL/025-C#.wav
AB_AeolinaL/026-D.wav
AB_violadamourL/rel99999/091-G.wav
AB_violadamourL/rel99999/092-G#.wav
AB_violadamourR/024-C.wav
AB_violadamourR/025-C#.wav

The extracted text should be:
cloch
grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde
grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde
AB_AeolinaL
AB_AeolinaL
AB_violadamourL/rel99999
AB_violadamourL/rel99999
AB_violadamourR
AB_violadamourR

Can anyone recommend a strategy using R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `stringr` package `str_remove(string,pattern)` function like:

```
str = "grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde/038-D.wav"
str_remove(str,"/[0-9]+[-]*[A-Z]*[#]*[.][a-z]+")
```

Output:

```
> str_remove(str,"/[0-9]+[-]*[A-Z]*[#]*[.][a-z]+")
[1] "grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde"
```

Then you can just iterate over all other strings:

```
strings <- c("cloch/51.wav",
             "grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde/038-D.wav",
             "grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde/039-D#.wav",
             "AB_AeolinaL/025-C#.wav",
             "AB_AeolinaL/026-D.wav",
             "AB_violadamourL/rel99999/091-G.wav",
             "AB_violadamourL/rel99999/092-G#.wav",
             "AB_violadamourR/024-C.wav",
             "AB_violadamourR/025-C#.wav")
str_remove(strings,"/[0-9]+[-]*[A-Z]*[#]*[.][a-z]+")
```

Output:

```
> str_remove(strings,"/[0-9]+[-]*[A-Z]*[#]*[.][a-z]+")
[1] "cloch"                                       
[2] "grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde"
[3] "grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde"
[4] "AB_AeolinaL"                                 
[5] "AB_AeolinaL"                                 
[6] "AB_violadamourL/rel99999"                    
[7] "AB_violadamourL/rel99999"                    
[8] "AB_violadamourR"                             
[9] "AB_violadamourR"
```

Comment: I also prefer the string removal to the substr methods, since that allows you to keep cases without `/` without additional code to catch those, but why not just use base R: `gsub("/[0-9]+[-]*[A-Z]*[#]*[.][a-z]+", "", strings)`?

Comment: I've been using so much of the `stringr` package that `gsub()` totally slipped my mind. Although I think I read somewhere that the `stringr` and `stringi` are a bit faster than the base package.

Comment: At least for this particular example `gsub` appears to be 3x faster, but we are talking about microseconds here, so it does not really matter. Just saying you don't need an extra package for that...

Answer (score 0):

You have to substract strings using this method:

```
substr(strings,1,regexpr("\\/[^\\/]*$", strings)-1)
[1] "cloch"                                       
[2] "grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde"
[3] "grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde"
[4] "AB_AeolinaL"                                 
[5] "AB_AeolinaL"                                 
[6] "AB_violadamourL/rel99999"                    
[7] "AB_violadamourL/rel99999"                    
[8] "AB_violadamourR"                             
[9] "AB_violadamourR"
```

Input

```
strings<-c("cloch/51.wav","grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde/038-D.wav","grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde/039-D#.wav","AB_AeolinaL/025-C#.wav","AB_AeolinaL/026-D.wav","AB_violadamourL/rel99999/091-G.wav","AB_violadamourL/rel99999/092-G#.wav","AB_violadamourR/024-C.wav","AB_violadamourR/025-C#.wav")
```

In which this regex `regexpr("\\/[^\\/]*$", strings)` gives you the position of the last "/"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the strings you propose are in a column of a dataframe:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = c("cloch/51.wav", 
                                "grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde/038-D.wav", 
                                "grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde/039-D#.wav", 
                                "AB_AeolinaL/025-C#.wav", 
                                "AB_AeolinaL/026-D.wav"))

# I define a function that separates a string at each "/" 
# throws the last piece and reattaches the pieces

cut_str <- function(s) {
  st <- head((unlist(strsplit(s, "\\/"))), -1)
  r <- paste(st, collapse = "/")
  return(r)
}

# through the sapply function I get the desired result

new_strings <- as.vector(sapply(df$y, FUN = cut_str))
new_strings

[1] "cloch"                                       
[2] "grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde"
[3] "grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde"
[4] "AB_AeolinaL"                                 
[5] "AB_AeolinaL"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```r
dirname(strings)
```

If there is no `/`, this returns `.`, which you could remove afterwards if you like, e.g.:

```r
res <- dirname(strings)
res[res=="."] <- ""
``
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start the match with `/` followed by 1 or more times any char except a forward slash or a whitespace char using a negated character class `[^\\s/]+`

Then match `.wav` at the end of the string using `$`

Replace the match with an empty string using sub for example.

`[^\\s/]+\\.wav$`

[See the regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/DokRkZ/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/vtXE7J)

```
strings <- c("cloch/51.wav",
             "grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde/038-D.wav",
             "grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde/039-D#.wav",
             "AB_AeolinaL/025-C#.wav",
             "AB_AeolinaL/026-D.wav",
             "AB_violadamourL/rel99999/091-G.wav",
             "AB_violadamourL/rel99999/092-G#.wav",
             "AB_violadamourR/024-C.wav",
             "AB_violadamourR/025-C#.wav")

sub("/[^\\s/]+\\.wav$", "", strings)
```

Output

```
[1] "cloch"                                       
[2] "grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde"
[3] "grand/Grand_bombarde/02-suchy_Grand_bombarde"
[4] "AB_AeolinaL"                                 
[5] "AB_AeolinaL"                                 
[6] "AB_violadamourL/rel99999"                    
[7] "AB_violadamourL/rel99999"                    
[8] "AB_violadamourR"                             
[9] "AB_violadamourR"
```